How to enable (turn on) a 5V power rail with a 3.3V MCU power rail?
My situation is the following.
I have a component that has a 5V line and a 3.3V one, the 5V line is used basically like an enable, while the 3.3V one is used to power the IC. If there is 5V but no 3.3V then the IC is fried.
So I thought about a N-channel mosfet in the following configuration

Which in theory should enable the 5V if and only if there is 3.3V.
Is this correct?

No, this is not correct. N-channel MOSFETs and npn BJTs are not suitable for use as high-side switches without additional complicating circuitry. Use it as a low-side switch, or use your signal to drive a proper load switch.

The symbol you're using is for a BJT, not a MOSFET!

What IC is this? It's unusual to have an input signal that has to exceed the supply voltage.

To turn an NPN BJT (the transistor in your schematic) on, you need to have a more positive potential on its base vs. emitter (Vbe voltage), by about 0.5-0.7V. If you were running a 3.3V through it and using 5V on its base (through a base resistor, you need to limit the base current or it will burn out) it would have worked, but your situation is the opposite. You could use a PNP BJT or a P-channel MOSFET as outlined in my answer. You DO NEED TO TELL US WHAT IS THE MAXIMUM CURRENT you expect running from the 5V rail through the transistor.

It is not a stupid question, it is better to ask and learn than to remain ignorant.
There are a few ways to do what you need.
Typically, the upper (positive) power rail is switched with a P-channel MOSFET, not the N-channel which is used for the lower (negative or ground) power rail (it can be used to switch the positive rail, but it needs a more complicated circuitry because its gate potential needs to be more positive than its source potential, in other words above the positive supply rail to turn it on).
Here is a typical solution for your situation:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When the 3.3V is off (switch open in this schematic), the P-channel MOSFET is off and there is no current going through it, because the gate-source resistor R1 virtually shorts those two electrodes.
When 3.3V is on (switch closed), the NPN bipolar junction transistor (BJT) is turned ON, and connects the MOSFET gate to GND, giving it the necessary NEGATIVE gate potential (relative to its SOURCE potential) needed to turn it on, thus the MOSFET is also ON and a current goes through it to the load.
PLEASE NOTE that you need a LOGIC LEVEL MOSFET, meaning it can be fully turned ON at 5V or less than 5V between its gate and source (this voltage is known and marked as Vgs or VGS, most standard MOSFETs fully turn on at between 6V and 8V VGS)!
In the schematic above, I have used a switch to allow you to simulate this circuit when you click on "simulate this circuit" below the schematic.
In your situation, there will be no switch, but a direct connection between +3.3V and R2.
There is a possible problem in that the 5V will be passed through the MOSFET even when the 3.3V is even less than 1V, in which case your MCU will not be working but its inputs/outputs will be exposed to 5V.
This can be easily solved by adding either a single RED or GREEN LED in series with the R2, or about 5 ordinary small-signal diodes like 1N4148, which will provide additional voltage drop between 3.3V and the base of Q1, thus not switching it ON until the 3.3V rail is at least 2.5V.
Here is such modification with an LED:

simulate this circuit
Here is such modification with standard diodes:

simulate this circuit
However, LEDs and diodes (or semiconductors in general) will change their characteristics with temperature and they are not all the same, so the solution below should be the best for you, using a resistor R3 between the base and the emitter of Q1, thus forming a voltage divider with R2, letting you adjust the voltage at which the Q1 and thus the MOSFET turn ON:

simulate this circuit
The Q1 transistor's turn-on point still depends on temperature, but you at least don't make it worse with diodes which make the total change even greater.
If you still insist on using a BJT (bipolar junction transistor), you can use it in a similar fashion, but it needs to be the PNP type, capable of passing the load current and you need to limit its base current with a resistor, as in the schematic below:

simulate this circuit
As you can see, you need much lower value resistors because BJTs need much larger current to turn them on.
R1 can be omitted, but it's better to leave it there, to make sure Q2 stays off when Q1 is off.


Is this correct?

No. The gate voltage of the N-mosfet needs to be several volts above 5V for the output to be at 5V. And that circuit doesn't solve the fundamental problem of overcurrent from the 5V source. You want switching and current limiting.

If there is 5V but no 3.3V then the IC is fried.

Put a series resistor - say 10kΩ to 100kΩ between the 5V source and the IC's enable input. It won't be fried then, since the current flowing into the ESD protection diodes will be small - between 0.5mA and 0.05mA, respectively.
You won't need to worry about adding mosfets or anything else. The current limiting resistor should do it all by itself.

But if you insist on switching the 5V line, four BJTs do the job - although there's a wide variety of other circuits that would work. This one has the benefit that it inherently limits the 5V current, since Q1-Q2 form a current mirror, as does Q3-Q4. The circuit is fairly insensitive to the transitor beta, and it should be fairly fast in reacting to loss of 3.3V, since only Q1 saturates, and with a fairly small base current.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
R1 converts the input voltage to current, and that current is then copied all the way to the "IC INPUT". Under normal operation, the IC INPUT should consume very little current - since it's a control pin. So a very small current will flow, Q1 will saturate, and the voltage on Q1's collector will be within mV of 5V.
On the other hand, should there be any fault that causes the IC to consume a higher current on the 5V control input, Q1 will come out of saturation and will limit the current to about 0.3mA. If you check the Absolute Maximum Ratings of the IC, there will be a maximum input current given for the shutdown pin. I think 0.3mA will prove to be well under the absolute maximum limit for that current, and the chip will survive this limited current flow.

The circuit you have shown will only give you about 2.6V at the load rather than 5V.
Here is a classic high-side switching using two BJTs of the same family as you show. You could also replace the SS8550 with a p-channel MOSFET such as AO3401 to give less than the ~100mV voltage drop shown (to only a few mV), however the peak current from the 5V supply to charge the 100nF will increase to more than 1.6A typically unless additional changes are made. The load is represented by the 100Ω resistor (about 50mA) and 100nF capacitor.

BUT notice how the 5V remains after the 3.3V turns off at 2ms because of the capacitor. So I'm concerned about your statement:

If there is 5V but no 3.3V then the IC is fried.

In fact this sounds like an X-Y problem where your real issue is connecting a signal between two different power domains safely, and in that case you may find it useful to use a voltage translator chip. Some of them have benign and defined behavior with supply voltages missing on either side.
In some special cases you may be able to use just a resistor to limit the current but there are various considerations with that method.

(Surprise: I'm afraid to become a chance.)
Suggest, Q1 has a B ~ 124.
Uemitterq2 ~ 2.7 Vmax (= 3.3 V - 0.6 Vbeq2).
Ir2 = 2.7 V / 47 kOhm = 57.5 uAmax  >>>
57.5 uA x Bq1 ~ 7.13 mAmax, the Icq1.
And the first circuit:  Ucomponent = 2.7 V  (= 3.3 V - 0.6 Vbe).
Component works like a resistor on Emmitter, current Anti-Coupling.

Copying a schematic, in this case from an earlier edit of my answer, requires attribution. Your annotations are nice of course.

Dear mister "Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica", sorry, you are right. I wrote about a schematic and the schematic was gone. Listen, to write about something and noone can understand what i mean that is a little bit unperfect. So i searched and searched and found it again and the rest you know. I am not in possession of this thing but please - schematic - stay here.
